# Why is this linked list program not giving any output?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

So I made these two simple functions regarding linked lists. One adds a node at the front and the other just displays the linked list in a sequence front to end. I'm wondering why this code wouldn't give me any output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
};
Node *head;

void addFront(Node *head, int item)
{
    Node *temp = new Node();
    temp->data = item;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
}
void traverse(Node *head)
{
    Node *temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    addFront(head, 1);
    addFront(head, 2);
    addFront(head, 3);
    traverse(head);
}
```

Comment: Because `temp` in `traverse()` is NULL before the loop starts.

Comment: Obligatory whining about C-style linked lists being taught with C++.

Answer (score 3):

You're operating on a copy of `head` pointer in `addFront()`. You have
to pass a pointer to pointer:

```
void addFront(Node **head, int item)
```

The entire code could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node
{
public:
  int data;
  Node *next;
};
Node *head;

void addFront(Node **head, int item)
{
  Node *temp = new Node();
  temp->data = item;
  temp->next = *head;
  *head = temp;
}

void traverse(Node *head)
{
  Node *temp = head;
  while(temp!=NULL)
    {
      cout << temp->data << " ";
      temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
  addFront(&head, 1);
  addFront(&head, 2);
  addFront(&head, 3);
  traverse(head);
}
```

Comment: I guess that's it. Thanks.

Comment: Then you should mark the answer as accepted, @GauravSingh.

Comment: @GauravSingh: If you like this answer please mark it as solved to let other users
know your problem is solved. Also see [What should I do when someone
answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Argument of addFront is input as well as output. (Node *head)
It needs to be passed as referenced